# PHP canvas image upload to remote server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvas, upload

I am trying to upload an canvas image(used html2canvas) to remote server,the filename is being created but the size is 0 bytes.

```
$(function click1() { 
    $("#share").click(function() { 
    $("#load").show();
        html2canvas($("#backdrop1"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
               var data1 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
     //display 64bit image
     var image = new Image();
    image.src = data1;
    $.ajax({
                        url: 'uploading.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {img_val: data1},
                        datatype: 'html',
                        success: function fbs_click1() {
    $("#load").hide();
}
                    });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The above Jquery code generates the elemnt image.

//Uploading.php

```
<?php
 $imaged = $_POST['img_val'];
 $filename  = $_FILES[$imaged]['tmp_name'];
 $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
 $data      = fread($handle,filesize($filename));
 $POST_DATA = array(
   'img_value' => base64_encode($data)
 );
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/upload.php');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close ($curl);
?>
```

And the server side handler script ie. upload.php

```
<?php
    $img = $_REQUEST['img_value'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = 'test.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
?>
```

Please help me, i have tried many ways to save but i am failing to do it.

Comment: do you have 2 servers? I mean handling `AJAX` request and storing image?

Comment: @Parixit I am trying to save the image from my localserver to remote server

Comment: Try removing "datatype: 'html' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code for your `AJAX`. You should directly pass image data received from `canvas` to server.

1. In browser,You receive base64 encoded image content
2. Then after you pass that content to your local server in plain text form.
3. On local server, you do not perform any action, just pass data via CURL in RAW format.
4. Finally you can store your image on your remove server.

Hope this helps!

**On client side:**

```
$(function click1() { 
    $("#share").click(function() { 
    $("#load").show();
        html2canvas($("#backdrop1"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
               var data1 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
               //display 64bit image
               var image = new Image();
               image.src = data1;
               $.ajax({
                   url: 'uploading.php',
                   type: 'post',
                   data: data1,
                   dataType: 'text',
                   contentType: "application/upload",
                   success: function fbs_click1() {
                      $("#load").hide();
                   }
               });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**On your local server (uploading.php) :**

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
   $imageData = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

   $curl = curl_init();    
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/upload.php" );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $imageData);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain')); 
   $result=curl_exec ($curl);
   echo $result;
   curl_close ($curl);
?>
```

**On your remove server (upload.php) :**

```
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
    $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
    $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

    $upload_dir = "PATH_TO_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY/";
    $final_img = $upload_dir."my_upload_image.png";

    if(file_put_contents($final_img, $unencodedData)) {
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
    else {
        echo 'ERROR';
    }
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR";
}
exit;
```

Comment: Its working,Thanks a lot for everyone who helped,may i know where did i go wrong?

Comment: @Cipher You were passing canvas content in `key/value` pair to server. Which was wrong, you should send that as it is in plain text format.

Comment: Oh my bad,Thanks a lot.

Comment: How can i pass two variables, i am not familiar with "HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA" method,Please help.

Comment: @Cipher You can't pass multiple variables easily. As it can be only pass as a string. So you have to manage multiple variables on your own like adding `separator` and `value`. Instead you can pass more variables in `GET/query string`

Comment: I just need to add an File_Name(ID),so i can access it from url,Is there any way i can pass the File_Id to the remote server

Comment: @Cipher Yes, as I said use `GET` parameter. Pass it in `url`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it simple then
1. remove upload.php
2. replace uploading.php with below code.

```
<?php
 $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $_POST['img_val']);
 $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
 $data = base64_decode($img);
 $file = 'test.png';
 $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
?>
```